# Unexpectedly poor zip compression result

Tags: python, numpy, zip, compression

This python script:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((10_000_000_000), dtype='u1')
np.savez_compressed('a-zip', a=a)
```

produces 9.7MB large file. Theoretically this array can be compressed to less than 100 bytes: 71 bytes for `.npy` header and a handful of bytes for 10,000,000,000 copies of `1`. Why is ZIP failing so badly here? Is there another compression algorithm easily available for NumPy array with better performance in simple cases similar to this one, with mostly the same value being used?

Comment: Is that really a case you need?

Comment: @KellyBundy Not exactly, but fairly close. See: *mostly the same value*. More than 98% of `1` and 99.9% of just 2 values: `1` and `2`.

Comment: And how poorly is your actual data compressed?

Comment: @KellyBundy 275MB is compressed down to 26.3MB. I have to deal with data sets ~100x larger.

Comment: Since you are saving just one array, you could `save` the `npy`, and experiment with compression like `gzip`.

Comment: " and a handful of bytes for 10,000,000,000 copies of 1" - **How did you determine** the value of "a handful"? Did you try reading the Zip specification? Did you try creating an uncompressed file and then giving it to a dedicated zipping program to see what output you get?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I was referring to the theoretical compression limit in my post. I tried using Zip (once) on uncompressed data, with the same result.

Comment: Right; so if you know that zipping it once gives you approximately that result regardless of how you zip, then you know that it's a question of how zip works, and thus nothing to do with your code. And no, it's naive to expect any given compression algorithm to get anywhere near the theoretical limit in pathological cases, unless you know they're specifically designed for that particular sort of pathological case.

Comment: Yes, the Kolmogorov complexity of 10 billion `1` bytes is pretty small, but deflate/gzip is the wrong compression algorithm for it.  You want something like run-length encoding, either as a first step to feed gzip, or just with a varint encoding for the run length to allow that 34-bit number (10M) to be encoded in 5 or 6 bytes, and the `u1` value in another byte.  For less trivial cases, you might still want RLE as an input to gzip or zstd, or delta compression like PNG uses (so you typically have small integers as the differences between adjacent pixels in a row).

Answer (score 3):

The deflate format, used by zip and gzip, inherently has a maximum compression ratio of 1032:1. Close to what you got.

One thing you could do is to simply compress it again. I compressed your output with gzip, and the result was 15822 bytes. In fact, it can be compressed a *third* time with gzip down to 639 bytes. You'll just need to decompress it that many times to restore it. (You could check for a gzip header and decompress if there is one, repeating that until there isn't a gzip header. Then do the npz decompression and extraction.)

Answer (score 2):

You could for example use [lzma](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html):

```
import numpy as np
import lzma

a = np.ones((10_000_000_000), dtype='u1')
with lzma.open('a-lzma', mode='wb') as f:
    np.savez(f, a=a)
```

Or double compression inspired by [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77241392/12671057):

```
with lzma.open('a-zip-lzma', mode='wb') as f:
    np.savez_compressed(f, a=a)
```

For size 1_000_000_000 (I don't have 10 GB memory), I get 972 KB your way, 145 KB with lzma, and 0.5 KB with the double compression.

Evidently neither compression is interested in absolutely optimizing such artificial extreme cases, *at the expense of realistic cases* (or at the expense of algorithm simplicity, or whatever other downsides it would have. The point is it wouldn't come for free. *Something* would *somehow* suffer). You'd better test with your actual data (and if you provide code generating data realistic for you, I can update my results as well).

**Update:** [bz2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html) produces 938 bytes with savez, and 485 bytes with savez_compressed. But now I'll stop compressing this artificial case. Ok one more: [zstd](https://github.com/indygreg/python-zstandard) produces 31 KB and 388 bytes, respectively.