# Is there a multicore option to compress a NumPy array?

Tags: python, compression, numpy-ndarray, multicore

I'm using `np.savez_compressed()` to compress and save a single large 4D NumPy array, but it uses only one CPU core. Is there an alternative, which can use many cores? Preferably something simple without need to code array split and compression of its pieces in multiple processes.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html says the `.npz` format is a ZIPed archive, which implies the compression algorithm is DEFLATE, aka LZ77, same as `gzip` / zlib implement.  It is possible to split data into blocks you compress separately with only a small loss of compression ratio, and still get a valid stream that `gunzip` can decompress (that's what `pigz` does; https://zlib.net/pigz/), so in theory it should be possible without breaking file-format compatibility.

Comment: But if you're looking for speed, something based on zstd (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zstd) compresses about 10x faster than zlib (per core) with similar compression ratio for most data, and the standard implementation of it was designed with threading in mind, chunking data so separate threads can work on separate chunks.  On an 8-core machine, optimistically a good implementation using that might be 80x faster than current `np.savez_compressed`, rather than just 8x.

Comment: (I have no idea if anyone's already written anything faster, but yes it should be very possible to do better than using a single thread to generate a ZIP file, with similar compression ratio.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm, I had already tried zstd in their previous question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77244016/12671057)) and with random data of 98% 1-bytes and 2% 2-bytes (similar to what they described), zstd was disappointing. At default level (3) its compression was ~20% **worse**, and at high enough level (13) to match the compression, it was about equally fast with two threads.

Comment: @KellyBundy Ok, maybe I was a bit optimistic about reaching an equal compression level.  It of course depends on the data.  Zstd does very well on ASCII text, but I wouldn't be surprised if some random binary data compresses significantly better with gzip.  20% larger might not be a problem if the total size is still a lot smaller than uncompressed, especially if that's the price you're paying for being what, 15 to 20x faster on a dual-core machine, vs. the single-threaded implementation of gzip?  At the fastest end of the speed/space tradeoff, there's LZ4, especially for fast *decompression*

Comment: @KellyBundy: For that specific data, run-length encoding as a first level might be useful, and zstd or gzip the RLE output?  As I just commented on that other question, for 10 billion identical bytes, RLE is the obvious best algorithm, e.g. with a varint encoding to make the whole thing about 7 bytes.  For flipping between `1` and `2`, if you know that's the case, make the values implicit and just encode the run lengths. Or just encode the lengths of the runs of `1`s, assuming one `2` between each run. So you emit a `0` length when there are back-to-back `2`s.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I've used zstd in the past for real-world data and it was very good. If their data is still like 98% 1-bytes and 2% 2-bytes, maybe a simple custom preprocessing in numpy (like representing streaks of 1-bytes as a single byte telling the length) would be both very fast and compress very well. I'd need some code from them to generate realistic data, though.

Comment: Oh, I see the OP's real data is *almost* all `1` and `2` bytes with that ratio.  So implict `2` doesn't work unless you come up with a way to signal a non-1-or-2 byte.  Perhaps a 0 in the RLE length signals that, and a 1 signals zero `2` bytes, and higher mean len-1 `1`s. Very different from *all* `1` bytes, but still could make an RLE pass worthwhile, especially if cache-blocked so zstd was working in chunks that were still hot in cache after RLE wrote them, and/or to overlap computation between RLE threads and zstd threads if you chunk that, too.

Comment: Or if raw zstd is "good enough" in terms of a speed / size tradeoff for their use case, that certainly saves some development effort. :P  Another thing you can do with tiny numbers is pack into 2-bit fields, four per byte, but if you're already using compression that's not helpful, @KellyBundy.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, those 0.1% other values made my test only "similar". They didn't say more about them, maybe they follow the pattern so it's mostly 3-bytes, fewer 4-bytes, etc. But even if they're random bytes, 0.1% shouldn't change things much, I think.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Yeah, I don't expect the .1% of other values to be significant, but it probably matters a lot how random the distribution of `2` bytes is.  e.g. if they tend to be grouped, then run-length encoding will be amazing.  And compressors like zstd can see patterns like `121121` occurring frequently if that's the case.  If they're randomly distributed, maybe 8-bit RLE with implicit values and two special bit-patterns: bytes from `2` to `255` encode 1 to 254 `1`s, a `1` encodes a `2` in the output, and `0` is an escape byte for a literal value.  Then feed that to zstd if that saves much

Comment: @PeterCordes An idea for RLE-like compression of such data (mostly 1, few 2, fewer 3, etc): Assume it's all 1. Then output the distances to the next increments. For example for input 1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,3 the output would be 3,5,0 (the 0 causes the same 1 to be incremented twice so it becomes 3). Lengths >255 could be encoded as 255 followed by the remaining length.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm... they said with their real data  *"275MB is compressed down to 26.3MB"*, whereas with my "similar" data (only 1 and 2, but random), I get ~9MB. Substantially different. I think I'll stop experimenting unless I get a realistic data generator.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Nice idea.  Compared to the last refinement of my idea (in the previous comment), that uses one more bit-pattern for lengths of runs of `1`s, and the `2`s don't cost a byte of their own.  The next most common value costs 2 bytes.  Depending on the distribution, instead of long runs of `0` to encode something like `10`, you might just use `0` to escape a literal byte.  Anyway, your 255 becomes a special case: it introduces a multi-byte length instead of just having two separate runs where the first is max-length.  So I guess `FF 00` would encode exactly 255.

Comment: @KellyBundy @PeterCordes Thank you for an interesting discussion. In this question, I care primarily about speed and ease of use, not the best compression ratio. `https://pypi.org/project/zstd/` seems to be a good option to try.